# How do I run an interactive GUI application in pre-login environment?

Tags: macos, login, ui

I am interested in writing an application which runs in a pre-login environment, i.e. right after a user enters their username and password, much like how OS X does the initial account setup:

[image]

How does this work? I've used [iHook](http://rsug.itd.umich.edu/software/ihook/) to run scripts, but I'd like to use replicate the same look and feel of Apple's initial account setup.

Comment: I doubt it's possible.  Apple can do that because it's integrated to the OS, which probably uses a private framework.  If you want to replicate that, your best bet would be to create a login item, and then create the effect you want.

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking into this for awhile myself.  Mike Bombich been able to do it for years with his Bootpicker app.  And this developer is able to tap into running a GUI app as soon as the user clicks on a login icon: https://github.com/grahamgilbert/crypt (can't tell from his screenshot, but look up his OS X Management with Puppet presentation).